# Unsuccessfully destructuring the object inside the function

Tags: javascript, react-native, destructuring

I have a js file name `index.js` inside a folder `utils`

Inside the file:

```
export const colors = {
  PRIMARY_COLOR: "#ff304f",
  SECONDARY_COLOR: "#002651",
  BORDER_COLOR: "#dbdbdb",
};
```

I try to destructuring it inside my `WeatherInfo` component like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image } from "react-native";

import { colors } from "../utils";

export default function WeatherInfo({ currentWeather }) {

  const { PRIMARY_COLOR } = colors;
  // console.log(colors);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.textPrimary}>{temp}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textPrimary: {
    fontSize: 40,
    color: PRIMARY_COLOR,
  },
});
```

I got error of saying `Can't find variable: PRIMARY_COLOR`, however if I `console.log(colors)` inside the function, I can see the object printed in the expo console. However, if I do it outside the function, it works. Can someone explain to me what happened?

Comment: The destructuring *is* successful, but `PRIMARY_COLOR` is accessible only in the function body where it's defined; I'd suggest reading up on *scope*.

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript/amp

Comment: Ok, I see. I think I got it. This is because I destructuring the colors inside the function. But the styles object is outside the function , thats why I cant access to the PRIMARY_COLOR. Thanks, I made a silly mistakes thanks @jonrsharpe

Comment: Just move outside the function, at the start of the module and the whole module will see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it right, but you just misplaced your code it should be outside from function body that's how it will be available on the whole page

```
const { PRIMARY_COLOR } = colors;
```

Move it up just one line.